# Good quantum number for the weak field Zeeman effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, hydrogen

To find the fine structure of hydrogen using nondegenerate perturbation theory, we choose the eigenstates of *L*<sup>2</sup>, *S*<sup>2</sup>, *J*<sup>2</sup>, and *J*<sub>z</sub>. As stated in Griffiths *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, the good quantum numbers are *n*, *l*, *s*, *j*, and *m<sub>j</sub>*.

For the weak-field Zeeman effect, the fine structure dominates and the Zeeman effect becomes the perturbation. The book states that the good quantum numbers are *n*, *l*, *j*, and *m<sub>j</sub>*. What about *s*? Why *s* is explicitly mentioned for fine structure but not for Zeeman effect? Is *s* suppressed since *s* is always 1/2?

Answer (score 0):

In the presence of a magnetic field $\vec B$, the Hamiltonian of this system is given by

$$H = -(\vec \mu_l + \vec \mu_s). \vec B$$

where $\vec \mu_s$ and $\vec \mu_l$ are the magnetic dipole moments for spin and orbital angular momentum respectively.

A “good set” of unperturbed energy eigenstates is given by $| n l j m_j \rangle$ and $m_l$ and $m_s$ are considered “not good” quantum numbers, since in the presence of spin-orbit coupling, the Hamiltonian $H$ does not commute with the operators $L$ and $S$. Operators that commute have computable simultaneous eigenvalues.

Note that in the strong-field limit, the unperturbed Hamiltonian does commute with $L^2$, $S^2$, $L_z$ and $S_z$, and so a “good set” of unperturbed energy eigenstates is given by $|n l m_l m_s \rangle$.

Probably funny terminology, but that is probably what the author is getting at.

Comment: All makes senses, but my questions still persist. Is _s_ a good quantum number for the weak Zeeman effect? Is _s_ term being dropped in |nljmj⟩ terminology because _s_ is always 1/2?

Comment: I don't think you understand. Do you know what $m_l$ and $m_s$ represent?

Comment: They are eigenvalues of angular momentum for z component, right? ml for Lz operator and and ms for Sz operator.